# SQL Server 2005 delete corrupt table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are having a database in which one table name dbo.ONOA is corrupt. We need to delete this table. Please let me is there any way to force delete the table?

Comment: what error are you receiving while dropping?

Comment: Also run `DBCC CHECKCATALOG` and post whatever errors you get here too. Its possible that you can't do the drop until you've fixed the errors.

Comment: Does `drop table YourTableName` not work??  If so, what error is thrown?

Answer (score 2):

Have you used [DBCC CHECKTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174338.aspx) to see what the problem is? Check the REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS | REPAIR_FAST | REPAIR_REBUILD options to potentially repair the table. Database must be set in single user mode.

Comment: Just want to clarify, since the separate sentences might be interpreted in strange ways. Be sure you use `CHECKTABLE`, not `CHECKDB`, with the `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` option. If you inadvertently do this at the database level and not the table level, you could irrevocably "repair" some other table that is having an issue you haven't yet detected. I know you aren't suggesting that at all @David, I just want to be sure people don't come across the `REPAIR` options and immediately associate them with `CHECKDB`.